# Что такое история undo/redo в программировании? ( Python 3, PyQt5 )

Tags: python, pyqt5

Что такое история undo/redo в программировании?

Данным вопросом я задался когда мне дали ответ на https://ru.stackoverflow.com. Я еще не дошел до такого уровня программирования чтоб это понимать или же я это еще не изучил.

Помогите с объяснением.

[image: Вот тот самый ответ с моего прошлого вопроса]

Comment: Посмотрите некоторые посты на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+undo+redo. Почитайте здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-undoframework-example.html. Ответьте на мой вопрос заданный в предыдущем вашем вопросе.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/306398/

Answer (score 0):

**Undo**(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) - кнопка "назад". Допустим, я написал код

`print('Hello World!')`,

а затем изменил `!` на `.`. Теперь если я нажму <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, то код *автоматически* изменится обратно (с `.` на `!`)

**Redo**(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>)
, соответственно, возвращает отменённые изменения. Если теперь я нажму <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, то `.` возвратится обратно.